# parsing bitcoin input and output addresses from scripts

Tags: script, public-key, signature

can someone walk me through the process of combining script inputs and outputs to reveal the base58 encoded input and output addresses. take for example, [block 728](http://blockexplorer.com/block/00000000d14f2e97678951ad004d6699babd27e07ca722c46b30dc24c67eed7a). this has two raw script inputs:

```
493046022100e26d9ff76a07d68369e5782be3f8532d25ecc8add58ee256da6c550b52e8006b022100b4431f5a9a4dcb51cbdcaae935218c0ae4cfc8aa903fe4e5bac4c208290b7d5d01

and

493046022100a2ab7cdc5b67aca032899ea1b262f6e8181060f5a34ee667a82dac9c7b7db4c3022100911bc945c4b435df8227466433e56899fbb65833e4853683ecaa12ee840d16bf01
```

the first byte of each (49 hex = 73 dec) is the instruction to push 73 bytes onto the stack. [according to the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Standard_Transaction_to_Bitcoin_address_.28pay-to-pubkey-hash.29) each of these input scripts consists of a signature and a public key.

the raw output script is

```
76a91412ab8dc588ca9d5787dde7eb29569da63c3a238c88ac
```

which translates to the instructions

```
OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHDATA0(20 bytes) 12ab8dc588ca9d5787dde7eb29569da63c3a238c OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG
```

**so given this information, how can i extract input addresses (as shown in blockexplorer.com)? is this even possible?**

```
1Miuw7ifaTYY5qrzKYFcTDiojSFxRfAqwP and 18KrJNtPVu6LWRNPQReqF29iFm7vDhirMk
```

and output address

```
12higDjoCCNXSA95xZMWUdPvXNmkAduhWv
```

Answer (score 12):

the output address is derived solely from the output script starting [from step 4 in the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_Bitcoin_addresses) like so:

first add leading zeros:

```
0012ab8dc588ca9d5787dde7eb29569da63c3a238c
```

then hash with sha256 ([if you look in the wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script) this is actually part of the OP_HASH160 operation) to give:

```
e158c4be10913422dadcf1c36843020ebb3ffe9d0cb13fb9e8c0a564a53c7832
```

then hashed with sha256 again (the wiki is wrong here - it says to use ripemd160, but actually sha256 is required again) to give:

```
96bf1d277213bbcd91145138e4c7ad8dcd6e1de1c39884fcbc1f5a6d4d7aee93
```

then grab the first 4 bytes of this result (`96bf1d27`) and stick them on the end of the original hash160 public key with leading zeros:

```
0012ab8dc588ca9d5787dde7eb29569da63c3a238c96bf1d27
```

convert to decimal:

```
457790304922245030616719694560989441716273193824169172263
```

base58 encode to give:

```
2higDjoCCNXSA95xZMWUdPvXNmkAduhWv
```

and stick a 1 in front of it all to get the bitcoin output address:

```
12higDjoCCNXSA95xZMWUdPvXNmkAduhWv
```

now to figure out how to get the input addresses...

[thanks to this answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/12556/2116), we can see that both the signatures are der encoded in the following format:

- 0x30: a header byte indicating a compound structure
- a 1-byte length descriptor for all what follows
- 0x02: a header byte indicating an integer
- a 1-byte length descriptor for the r value
- the r coordinate, as a big-endian integer
- 0x02: a header byte indicating an integer
- a 1-byte length descriptor for the s value
- the s coordinate, as a big-endian integer
- a hashtype byte

so, decoding the raw script signatures:

```
493046022100e26d9ff76a07d68369e5782be3f8532d25ecc8add58ee256da6c550b52e8006b022100b4431f5a9a4dcb51cbdcaae935218c0ae4cfc8aa903fe4e5bac4c208290b7d5d01
```

- 0x49 = OP_PUSHDATA0 - push 73 bytes onto the stack (script command not part of the signature value)
- 0x30 = header byte
- 0x46 = length descriptor (70 bytes)
- 0x02 = header byte
- 0x21 = r value length descriptor (33 bytes)
- `00e26d9ff76a07d68369e5782be3f8532d25ecc8add58ee256da6c550b52e8006b` the r coordinate as a big endian integer
- 0x02 = header byte
- 0x21 = s value length descriptor (33 bytes)
- `00b4431f5a9a4dcb51cbdcaae935218c0ae4cfc8aa903fe4e5bac4c208290b7d5d` the s coordinate as a big endian integer
- 0x01 = hashtype byte

and the second raw signature has the same format too:

```
493046022100a2ab7cdc5b67aca032899ea1b262f6e8181060f5a34ee667a82dac9c7b7db4c3022100911bc945c4b435df8227466433e56899fbb65833e4853683ecaa12ee840d16bf01
```

- 0x49 = OP_PUSHDATA0 - push 73 bytes onto the stack (script command not part of the signature value)
- 0x30 = header byte
- 0x46 = length descriptor (70 bytes)
- 0x02 = header byte
- 0x21 = r value length descriptor (33 bytes)
- `00a2ab7cdc5b67aca032899ea1b262f6e8181060f5a34ee667a82dac9c7b7db4c3` the r coordinate as a big endian integer
- 0x02 = header byte
- 0x21 = s value length descriptor (33 bytes)
- `00911bc945c4b435df8227466433e56899fbb65833e4853683ecaa12ee840d16bf` the s coordinate as a big endian integer
- 0x01 = hashtype byte

so this confirms that the signature values in the transaction inputs actually do not contain public keys at all. the input addresses actually come from the previous transaction outputs which can be identified through the input hash and input index in the current tx.

Comment: this may provide a method of getting the public key from the signature alone https://github.com/nanotube/supybot-bitcoin-marketmonitor/blob/master/GPG/local/bitcoinsig.py

Comment: also, this shows how the signature is created http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/5241/2116

Comment: Great answer. Wish I could up vote more.

Answer (score 2):

my solution was, that I passed the hex string to:

```
    def publicKeyDecode(pub):
            hash1 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(pub))
            hash2 = hashlib.new('ripemd160', hash1.digest())
            padded = (b'\x00') + hash2.digest()
            hash3 = hashlib.sha256(padded)
            hash4 = hashlib.sha256(hash3.digest())
            padded += hash4.digest()[:4]
            return base58.b58encode(padded)
```

Comment: had to use `sha256` instead of `ripemd160` to get the correct address

Comment: Had to comment out the first line (pub = pub[2:-2]) to work with the public key (0250863ad64a87ae8a2fe83c1af1a8403cb53f53e486d8511dad8a04887e5b2352) on the wiki (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Technical_background_of_version_1_Bitcoin_addresses)

Comment: Everything depends on the script itself. because it is a program. so you have to interpret it on your own. The above solution was a standard script decoding. Someone edited it, so its not correct for all scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a python3+ implementation for @mulllhausen's answer on parsing the Bitcoin address from the P2PKH script:

```
import binascii
import hashlib
import base58

def P2PKHToAddress(pkscript, istestnet=False):
    pub = pkscript[6:-4] # get pkhash, inbetween first 3 bytes and last 2 bytes
    p = '00' + pub # prefix with 00 if it's mainnet
    if istestnet:
        p = '6F' + pub # prefix with 0F if it's testnet
    h1 = hashlib.sha256(binascii.unhexlify(p))
    h2 = hashlib.new('sha256', h1.digest())
    h3 = h2.hexdigest()
    a = h3[0:8] # first 4 bytes
    c = p + a # add first 4 bytes to beginning of pkhash
    d = int(c, 16) # string to decimal
    b = d.to_bytes((d.bit_length() + 7) // 8, 'big') # decimal to bytes
    address = base58.b58encode(b) # bytes to base58
    if not istestnet:
        address = '1' + address # prefix with 1 if it's mainnet
    return address

print(P2PKHToAddress("76a91412ab8dc588ca9d5787dde7eb29569da63c3a238c88ac")) # 12higDjoCCNXSA95xZMWUdPvXNmkAduhWv
```